# Is there a dom inspector flag for Fennec?

Tags: mozilla, fennec, dom-inspector

I've got Dom Inspector installed on Fennec on my desktop, and sometimes the cmd+shift+i hotkey works and sometimes it doesn't (or maybe I'm forgetting it?).. so I"m wondering if anyone knows if there is a command line flag that I can use to open the dom inspector when Fennec opens?

Comment: Desktop Fennec is no different than regular Firefox, it is merely a different user interface. Meaning in particular: same command line flags as John notes correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same argument as works with Firefox works for me:

```
fennec -inspector <URL>
```

Comment: Note that this will even open Inspector if Fennec is already running which is rather convenient.